# How to prevent my music player from starting after my phone rings and I hang up?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, android-mediaplayer

This code works. The only problem I have is when I'm NOT using the app and the phone rings, the music plays after I hang up.

```
public void level_one(View view){

        mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alpha_12);

        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    mp3.pause();
                } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    mp3.start(); // Runs this line even if I didn't play
                } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    mp3.pause();
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(mgr != null) {
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a `PhoneStateListener` in the first place? Wouldn't properly handling `AudioFocus` events automatically cover phone calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just introduce a boolean which keeps track of whether the music was previously playing. I've just made up your surrounding class but you get the idea.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private boolean isMusicPlaying = false;

    public void someFunctionWhichStartsMusic()
    {
        //start the music

        isMusicPlaying = true;
    }

    public void level_one(View view){

        mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alpha_12);

        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                {
                    mp3.pause();
                }
                else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
                          && isMusicPlaying) // pay attention to this!
                {
                    mp3.start();
                }
                else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)
                {
                    mp3.pause();
                }
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            }
        };
        TelephonyManager mgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(mgr != null) {
            mgr.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
    }
}
```